# How to import file with only extension?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-register

I wish import a file with only an extension (no name) : `.sec`. This file contains a json object with security parameters like login and password. The goal is to add the extension in `.gitignore` file to never save this file in a git repository.

I use `babel-register` and `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` to convert `esmodulle` to `commonjs`. I added the new extension to babel-register options :

```
{
    "extensions": [".es6", ".es", ".js", ".sec"]
}
```

If I name the file `security.sec` and import it, all works. 
But if I name the file `.sec` when I import it, I have the error:

> Cannot find module '.sec'

So how to import a file without name? Is this the right way to do this? Is there an existing file extension to save security parameter?

Comment: well i import explicitly `.sec`, so i wish import only `.sec` file not `*.sec` files

Comment: Oh, nevermind, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the path to '.sec'

eg

> const sec = require('./.sec')

You could also check out the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module.